# remapping k to the right shift button

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap, remapping

I have been looking on askubuntu for help, but couldn't find the help I needed, so now I just ask.

My k key doesn't work, when pressed, and since its a older laptop, i just wish to remap the k key unto the right shift.

From what I have gathered, I need to use xmodmap and xev, but I can't figure out how to remap the k key in question.

(Copy pasting 'k' is getting very annoying xD )

Hope some of you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Also why your <k> key isn't working? is it broken? what is the output of pressing that on running `xev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open teminal and type this command

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = k"
```

then run this command

```
xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap
```

now press <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> , you will see typed "k"

Activate the changes(for this login session only) with following command:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Making changes persistent across reboots:

If it doesn't exist, create a file in your home folder called `.xinitrc`.

```
touch .xinitrc
```

Place the following line in the file and save the file:

```
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Comment: My k key is broken, so there is no output when i press it :)

Comment: How do I save it, so that after a reboot, it still is at Right Shift?
I have tried typing just as you say, but after a reboot I have to type it all over :)

Comment: @RasmusNielsen I have updated my answer.

Comment: For some reason I can't make a file using the 'touch' command, nor with >newfile or making a textfile called .xinitrc :s

I know its a bit of a pain,but I'm quiet new to ubuntu :)