# How can I remove a single temporary key mapping without resetting the entire keymap?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

So I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517505/remapping-k-to-the-right-shift-button) the other day. The user's <kbd>K</kbd> key was broken and they wanted to map it to Right-<kbd>Shift</kbd>. A good answer popped up and I thought I'd test it to see if it worked. I ran:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = k"
```

I did this under the understanding that I never use Right-<kbd>Shift</kbd> for anything. It turns out I was completely wrong. I use it all day long.

I've been filling up documents, corrupting commands, even *almost* deleting the wrong things (with Right-<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>). It's been a roller-coaster of emotions, but now I want it to go away. I'm sorry universe.

I know I could reboot or even just restart X but I have a load of things running and work to do. Can I just remove the mapping that `xmodmap` has created so that Right-<kbd>Shift</kbd> is just Right-<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

In this case it's just a single mapping (so Etcher Sketch approaches will work for me) but assume I have other mappings that I want to keep.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/q/29603/158442

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Shift_R"
```

I used `xmodmap -pke` to see the list of current mappings, and look up Left-<kbd>Shift</kbd>. The right one follows from symmetry.

Comment: @Oli why/Have you not tried `xmodmap` command again (for selecting Right Shift) yourself?

Comment: @Pandya I wondered if it was a trick question, but then after a few tries I realised that the name for Right Shift might be the problem. Until I ran it with `-pke` I had guessed R_Shift, RShift, RightShift, etc.